# Is seeking to specific frames of an MJPEG video faster than doing the same for an h.264 file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gstreamer, h.264, mjpeg

I am recording video and will need to seek to a specific frame in the video quickly and randomly.

I can record the video in MJPEG or h.264 compression standards.

I understand that MJPEG produces individual jpegs and produce larger file sizes than h.264, and h.264 compresses across multiple frames of video.

> Does this difference mean that I will get faster seek times when
>   seeking to a random location in the file using ffmpeg or gstreamer
>   programmatically?
>
> Will the MJPEG allow the frame-seek operation to reduce the IO requirements when reading just 1 frame from a video file?

Comment: That's easy to test with ffmpeg, right? But probably yes (comparing defaults), although one could probably use h264 in some intra-only mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for MJPEG.
If you are looking for specific (Nth) frame, in H.264 case you must find the closest I-frame to the frame you seek, then **decode all the frames between this I-frame and the Nth frame and even further if the Nth frame is a B-frame** to restore full Nth frame. It takes milliseconds but may be critical for you.
MJPEG will have larger file size but no decoding overhead, so it is your choice unless your disk is very-very-very slow.
In any case, ffmpeg must go through all the video packets to count them so it is a tradeoff between your disk and processor speed.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, FFmpeg 2.1+ *can* extract frames very quickly from h.264, too. Assuming you specify the desired frame by a timepoint, it doesn't need to "go through all the video packets to count them", as stated in the accepted answer. I also don't think there's a way to request the *Nth* frame (other than multiplying *N* by a fixed frame rate to determine the desired timepoint).

Here's an example, using an h.264 version of the freely-available animated short, ["Big Buck Bunny"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Buck_Bunny).

Let's ask for an exact frame, precisely 10 minutes into the video:

`$ ffmpeg -ss 00:10:00.000 -i /home/eric/Videos/bbb_sunflower_2160p_30fps_normal.mp4 -y -vframes 1 -s 3840x2160 /tmp/bbb-10:00.000.jpg`

That extraction took only about 1.8 seconds.

**Beware**: If you reverse the `-i` and -`ss` arguments, you are "output seeking" (rather than "input seeking"). In this case "[...the input will be decoded (and discarded) until it reaches the position given by -ss. This will be done very slowly, frame by frame.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)"

For example:

`$ ffmpeg -i /home/eric/Videos/bbb_sunflower_2160p_30fps_normal.mp4 -ss 00:10:00 -y -vframes 1 -s 3840x2160 /tmp/bbb-10:00.000.jpg`

Extracting that took about 12 min 45 secs (note that the *movie itself* is under 11 minutes long!). So on my machine, it's running at less than realtime.

More details on "seeking" with FFmpeg can be found here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking